# Bash script which kills a process by partial name match

Tags: bash

I have a very small script called `processKiller` which kills a process given a partial name match on a running service.

Right now, I have as my script:

```
ARG=$1
sudo pkill -f $ARG -9
```

And this works. It just prints `killed`, whether it kills something or not. However, I want to be able to set a var to the user's input, if it is able to find a process with the partial match. So say I have a process called `MyProcess-01-02` and the user types in their cmd line:

> processKiller.sh MyPro

I would like it to output:

> Killed: MyProcess-01-02

I thought of something like this, but it's not setting the variable correctly. Any ideas?

```
ARG=$1
SERVICE = -f $ARG
sudo pkill -f $SERVICE -9
echo "Killed: $SERVICE"
```

Also, would there be any way to run an "if" check on the SERVICE variable once found to only kill if it is indeed already running?

Comment: Consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-e` option of `pkill` to show what is being killed:

```
pattern=$1
pkill -e -9 "$pattern"  # Remember to quote your arguments
```

Example:

```
pkill -e xyz
xyz killed (pid 8105)
xyz killed (pid 8109)
xyz killed (pid 8110)
xyz killed (pid 8111)
xyz killed (pid 8112)
xyz killed (pid 8113)
xyz killed (pid 8114)
xyz killed (pid 8115)
xyz killed (pid 8116)
```

If you don't like this output format, you can change it using `sed`:

```
pkill -e -9 "$pattern" | sed -re 's/^(\S+).*/Killed: \1/'
```

Comment: Don't forget he wants to use a script and the name he's looking for will also be an argument of the script, so this will: 1) kill the script itself, so you won't be able to add commands after that line in case you want to; 2) always kill something (the script itself) even if what he was looking for was not running at all

Comment: @JoãoMiranda: I don't understand why this should kill the script itself

Comment: Well, he will call the script with "processKiller.sh MyPro". When you run "pkill -e -f -9 "$PATTERN"" his script will also be in the list of processes that pkill is going to kill, because "processKiller.sh MyPro" will be in the list of processes and it will also match the pattern. It's just because he will use the pattern as an argument to the script.

Comment: Oh, right, it's because of `-f`. I removed it as (by reading the question) I don't think it's necessary. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Not ideal to be showcasing all-caps variable names in a teaching resource -- see relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, specifying all-caps names for variables with meaning to the system or shell, and reserving the namespace with at least one lowercase variable for application use.

Comment: Addressed that concern as well

Comment: neither of these suggestions seem to work for me, even when adding `sudo` before the pkill line

Comment: The `-f` seems to be necessary, as that's the character that looks for something based on partial match.

Comment: @NateH06: if you need `-f`, then you need to match _arguments_, not program names. That was not clear from your question

Comment: I do, that is mostly the point of the script, sorry if I was not clear. The second suggestion works pretty well when re-adding `-f`, but it just prints `"Killed: sudo" ` or `"Killed: java"`, but never actually the full service name as listed under the `cmd` column when you run `ps -ef`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach can be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#get the argument
processNameToFind="$1"

#find any process lines with that name
processLines=$(ps o pid,command | grep "$processNameToFind" | grep -v "$0" | grep -v "grep")

#let's see if we found something
if [ -n "$processLines" ]
then
    #we may have found multiple processes running
    while read -r pid processName
    do 
        #kill it        
        sudo kill -9 "$pid"
        echo "Killed: $processName"
    done <<< "$processLines"
else
    echo "No process was found with the name: $processNameToFind"
fi
```

A few points to note:

- grepping the results from *ps* can be tricky and the results may vary from system to system; you may have to adapt it to yours
- *pgrep* is usually preferred to find a pid based on a name, but you want not only the pid but also the name; that's why we're grepping the results of *ps*
- you want to use this inside a script and you're using the name of the process you want to search for as an argument to both the script and the grep, so we'll remove the script's name and the grep from the *ps* results
- it's assumed that in case you have more than one process running you'll want to kill all of them and not just the first on the list, hence the while
- we're not checking the exit status of the *kill* command, we're just printing that we killed it, assuming it was successful
- we have the else in case we didn't find the process, but this is optional, of course
- with this approach you're able to kill processes based on the whole line used to run the process (command plus arguments)

edit: updated with tips from Charles Duffy

Comment: Why postprocess with `awk`? The shell can split things out for you: `while read -r pid processName; do ...` will have the same effect (first column to `pid`, all remaining columns to `processName`).

Comment: This is really close, but it seems like it doesn't catch everything on the partial match. It kills one thing with the partially matching name, but not the other one I see listed when I run a `ps -ef` command.  So, for example under the `cmd` column, I have one process named: ` sudo -u application_user MyProcess-01-02-` this one it killed. However, I have another called `/bin/java -cp /opt/MyProcess-01-02-SNAPSHOT/lib` , and this still runs